# First row of tableview is hidden by search bar iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I added the search bar to the tableview. When i start search first row of search result is getting hidden. I tried the following way to rectify it but it doesn't work.

```
self.categoryTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should first check your row height if it corresponds to the height of the cell.

Comment: Make sure you return this value for - tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
 and appropriate height for header at - tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: if search bar is part of your header.

Comment: either you keep your searchbar inside the header view of the uitableview or set the y pos for uitableview with ui search bar height. I mean placing  uitableview below uisearchbar in scene or xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following it worked fine.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *view;
    if(isFiltered)
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.categoryTableView.frame.size.width, 45)];
    }
    else
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    }
    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(isFiltered)
    {
        return 45;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc]         initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.categoryTableView.frame.size.width, 60)] ;
   [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  UISearchBar *txtSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,self.categoryTableView.frame.size.width - 20 , 40)];
[headerView addSubview:txtSearchBar]; 
self.categoryTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Comment: search bar is not added in to tableview